# how to change the specified rows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have the next code :

```
 private void Install_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
            var link = File.ReadLines(path + "config.ini").ToArray();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var txt in link)
            {
                if (txt.Contains("PLP="))
                {
                    var PLPPath = txt.Split('=')[1];
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("fileInstallationKey = {0}", PLPPath));

                }
                else if (txt.Contains("Output="))
                {
                    var outputPath = txt.Split('=')[1];
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("outlog= {0}", outputPath));
                }
                else if (txt.Contains("Licfile="))
                {
                    var LicFilePath = txt.Split('=')[1];
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("license_path= {0}", LicFilePath));
                }
 }
            File.WriteAllText(path + "installer.ini", sb.ToString());


        }
```

With this I want to replace in `Installer.ini` just this rows `sb.AppendLine(string.Format("fileInstallationKey = {0}", PLPPath));`

```
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("outlog= {0}", outputPath));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("license_path= {0}", LicFilePath));
```

other rows should not be changed. How I can do this ?? with this code I rewrite the file installer.ini, and I don't want this

Comment: Why don't you replace the texts (PLP to fileInstallationKey,Output to outlog,Licfile to license_path) using Replace() function?

Comment: you say to replace appendLine with Replace ()??

Comment: you can give me the code, to do this ?

Comment: just did ! but it is not tested for an ini, so please try it & let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure,since its an ini & not a plain text file, but this should work :

```
string configfilename=path +"config.ini";
string installerfilename=path +"installer.ini";

string configtext = File.ReadAllText(configfilename);
string installertext = File.ReadAllText(installerfilename);

if(configtext.Contains("PLP") )
    installertext = installertext.Replace("PLP", "fileInstallationKey")
if(configtext.Contains("Output") )
    installertext = installertext.Replace("Output","outlog")
if(configtext.Contains("Licfile") )
    installertext = installertext.Replace("Licfile","license_path");
File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, installertext);
```

Comment: but here It's not mentioned the destination installer.ini

Comment: WriteAllText to the destination path. Answer edited.

Comment: this code makes a copy of config.ini in installer.ini, just rows who are in config are copied in installer.ini, and all I have in installer was deleted

Comment: Yes, thats what it does. So, You want to replace the data in config.ini or installer.ini? how does these files related?

Comment: I want to edit data from installer.ini, but just edit not replace

Comment: then why do you need config.ini?

Comment: your question suggests that you are checking the values in config.ini, if they are present you are modifyin the installer.ini file. assuming that i will update the answer.let me know if i understood it wrong.

Comment: you this I want to do

Comment: done ! check this & lemme know if this is what you wanted :)

Comment: Do not write anything in installer.ini

Comment: installer.ini remain the same

Comment: the reason for which this code doesn't work it's not because we doesn't get the values after equal??? like here var PLPPath = txt.Split('=')[1]; ???

Comment: I think you need to be more clear , coz I am not getting what i am missing from the requirement..!!